# Efficiency of clustering/classification of data that have shared "possible" properties but the properties must be exclusive

Tags: classification, clustering

There is a data set of people that have an interest in `x >= 1` clubs. Each person has to attend exactly three of these clubs (if they have an interest in `x < 3` clubs, then they only need to attend `x` clubs). The clubs must be grouped into schools where all members of these clubs must go to this school, and each person can only attend one school. The schools should have approximately even distributions of people ~(# of people / # of schools).

Currently, I have two mappings of `person : clubs they have an interest in` and `club : interested people`. Of course there will be clubs with incredible popularity and some with only one interested person. Working bottom up (starting with clubs with low interest and branching off into those people) is the best way to avoid having massive clubs at the end, but still has the concern of overly large groupings of clubs. Would minimizing on randomly chosen club/people clusters perform better in the long run? Could this be tackled as a classification problem?

EDIT (Thanks to a recommendation from a colleague): Another way to explain the brute force method is: find all partitions of the set of clubs. For each partition, see if there is there is a solution that every student has a school they can attend that satisfies the constraint of `x` required clubs. Save all accepted solutions and, after running through all partitions, find the accepted solution with the best distribution.

EDIT2: Finding the list of all partitions for the set of clubs gets unpractically large as the number of clubs increases. (see "Bell number")

EDIT3: If we have a set number of schools (subsets in a partition), then we can drastically cut down on the list of all partitions. (see "Stirling numbers of the second kind")

Comment: I'd look at this as a **set cover** problem rather than a clustering problem. You want to cover all people with clubs, and all clubs with schools. So it likely is an NP hard problem, and you need some approximation.

Comment: Thank you for that connection and after taking a look at "set cover" problems, they do seem relevant to this question. However, it looks like the common usage of "set cover" problems is to minimize the set of clubs where all students are included at least once.

Comment: You could consider answer set programming using a tool like dlv to solve your problem.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, if I were to use something like dlv or prolog to code it, wouldn't it just be a faster brute force? The input sizes will be large (1000's clubs and 10000's of students). I was wondering if there were some shortcut/approximation algorithms that would be applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of a quicker solution. But again I have an idea for a different formulation of the problem. What about using a graph database like neo4j and standard graph algorithms to solve the problem?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, I changed gears and now am generating a partition of schools first (ex. by kmeans clustering on geographical data). Then I go through each person and see if there is a subset of schools that meets the constraint for that person (has `x` clubs that the person is interested in). If there isn't a solution, we have the number of people that didn't fit anywhere and deal with that data however we want. We can run this over and over again (adding some randomness) minimizing on the # of people that didn't fit in a subset.